# Sql about update

Tags: sql

Let we have a production database on a large web application like Ebay. Let we have two tables:

```
table Menu  
  MenuID int,  
  ... -- // Other Menu columns  

 table MenuItem   
     MenuItemID int,   
     MenuID int, -- // Points to Menu table.   
   ... -- // Other Menu item columns
```

Let we have Menu row with MenuID = 1 and several MenuItem rows with MenuID = 1 we need to change MenuID to 2. How to implement this?

Comment: All rows with MenuID 1 should be changed to 2? Also, what DBMS are you using, could you tag it in your question?

Comment: Probably, "on update cascade" is the declaration you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

> Let we have Menu row with MenuID = 1 and several MenuItem rows with
>   MenuID = 1 we need to change MenuID to 2. How to implement this?

Try following SQL query:

```
Update [MenuItem]    --Table to update
Set MenuID = 2   --Set MenuID to 2
Where MenuID = 1 --Where MenuID is equal to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough!

```
UPDATE
  MenuItem
SET
  MenuItem.MenuID = 2
WHERE
  MenuItem.MenuID = 1;
```